# Any issue with this as a password generator?

Tags: strings, random, powershell

Was trying to create a password generator like the one Bitwarden has...

Curious if anyone sees any issues with this? (wordlist shortened for readability)

There perhaps there's a more efficient way I've over looked?

**Code**

```ps
$wl = @("abacus","abdomen","abdominal","abide","abiding","ability","ablaze","able","abnormal","abrasion","abrasive","abreast","abridge","abroad","abruptly","absence","absentee","absently","absinthe","absolute","absolve","abstain","abstract","absurd","accent","acclaim","acclimate","accompany","account","accuracy","accurate","accustom","acetone","achiness","aching","acid","acorn","acquaint","acquire","acre")
function Gen-Pass {
    Param ($WordList)
    $ti = (Get-Culture).TextInfo
    $r_words = $WordList | get-random -count 3 
    $r_index = get-random -min 0 -max 3
    $r_num = get-random -min 0 -max 10
    $r_words[$r_index] += $r_num.tostring()
    $pw = "$($ti.totitlecase($r_words[0]))-$($ti.totitlecase($r_words[1]))-$($ti.totitlecase($r_words[2]))"
    return $pw
}

foreach ($n in 1..5) {
    Gen-Pass -WordList $wl
}
```

**Sample output**

```
Abstract-Absolve-Abdominal6
Accurate5-Accuracy-Abstain
Acre2-Accurate-Abstract
Acre-Acquire2-Account
Absurd4-Acclimate-Aching
```

Comment: `get-random` isn't crypto-secure you might want to use `$RandomNumberGenerator=[System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider]::Create()`

Answer (score 4):

Your code looks quite neatly done.

I would likely make a few changes:

1. make the number of words to use a parameter [with a default value].
   3 is a good starting point, but folks may want 4 or more ... so give them the option.
2. use an external word source. There are several word lists online. something like ... https://github.com/dwyl/english-words

   Be careful NOT to pound that source, thogh. I would check my temp dir to see if the file was already there - and only download the file if it ain't present.
3. the `-Count` parameter of `Get-Random` gives up to that number of *unique* items. That means you will not get the same word twice. You lose a little complexity ... so it is worth keeping it in mind.
4. you can directly join the items in an array. So, instead of ...

   ```
   $pw = "$($ti.totitlecase($r_words[0]))-$($ti.totitlecase($r_words[1]))-$($ti.totitlecase($r_words[2]))"
   ```

   You can use ...

   ```
   $pw =  $r_words -join '-'
   ```
5. you can apply the title case method to a hyphen delimited string! So you can do ...

   ```
   $pw =  (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($r_words -join '-')
   ```
6. the `-Max` parameter of `Get-Random` is another "off by one" thing. The range is NOT `Min..Max` ... it is `Min..(Max - 1)`. so your ...

   ```
   $r_index = get-random -min 0 -max 3
   ```

   ... will never get a `3`. it will get `0..2`.

   The way to get around that is to use a range and the `-InputObject` parameter. like this ...

   ```
   Get-Random -InputObject $MinMaxRange
   ```

---

Just for giggles, here is one of my attempts at the password/passphrase idea ...

Passphrase/Password maker - v2 - Pastebin.com
— https://pastebin.com/srCbxcmD

Comment: thank you for your input!
[1] understood - this is just for an API to create temp pass, but I can totally see how it could be extended for other things, and having the ability to customize would be useful.
[2] It's actually using the eff one you reference in your pastebin :) but it's stored locally as an array so it doesn't download it constantly. 
[3] ah - this I did not know. I suppose on a technical level it makes sense to have the ability for the same word to be chosen (more random)
[4] & [5] perfect I've implemented this!
[6] by design only 3 words so index 0-2 yields 3

Comment: @meowsoftly - you are most welcome! glad to have helped somewhat ... [*grin*]